# Perl if statement, If value = nothing do statement if value = something do statement

Tags: mysql, perl, xampp

I am trying to insert a value from a text box into a SQL table. Although when I leave the text box blank it is adding a blank value which then causes the rest of the form functions to not work.

I want the `if` statement to check if $animal is blank do nothing. And if $animal has something in it, then to perform the insert into the table.

I am not quite sure what to put where I have put.

```
if ($animal = " ") {
}
else
    if ($animal = "???") {
        insertTable("INSERT INTO $table(name) VALUE ('".$animal."')");
```

Line 24 - 27 is this

```
sub insertTable {
    $statement = shift (@_);
    $dbh->do($statement);
}  # sub
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, it will return the value of the right hand side parameter (in your case `" "` and `"???"`). You want `==`.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` will warn you about using an assignment in a conditional. Just one of the reasons why they're a Really Good Idea.

Answer (score 6):

Perl uses scalar variables, which are quite versatile little things. One of the gotchas with them is that their 'truthiness' isn't always obvious.

If you test a scalar with a Boolean test it will be false if:

- It's undefined.
- It's an *empty* string.
- It's the number 0.
- It's the string "0".

(Arrays test as false if they're undefined *or* have no elements.)

So the correct answer would be - either used `defined` to check if the value is defined. Or use a regular expression to pattern match a 'valid' value.

E.g.

```
if ( $animal =~ m/\w+/ ) {
    # Do something
}
```

`\w+` is the Perl regular expression for saying 'one or more word characters' which is alphanumeric and underscore. So your empty string, whitespace only string, or undefined string will all not match this pattern.

Comment: I get this error now after pressing submit in the HTML form when I try to insert into the table :                                DBD::mysql::db do failed: Unknown column 'snake' in 'field list' at J:/xampp/htdocs/webprog/cal/recordAnimalsMass.pl line 26.

Comment: That's not a perl error. To troubleshoot that we'll need more of your code.

Answer (score 5):

Quite a few problems here. Addressing the worst of them:

1. You're using `=` which is for assignment, not comparison. Use `==` to compare numbers and `eq` to compare strings.
2. You're comparing your variable to a single space. It's very unlikely that you'll get a single space character in $animal. You'll want to do something either far simpler (`if ($animal) { ... }`) or more complex (perhaps `if ($animal =~ /\w/) { ... }`).
3. You are interpolating user input directly into SQL which you then run against your database. This leads to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). Far better to use a bind point in your SQL.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings` will address point 1. Which sort of suggests the OP doesn't have these modes turned on. `Found = in conditional, should be == at line 5.`

Answer (score -1):

In Perl there isn't a null value, only an undefined!

```
if (defined $value)
{
  # Do that
}
else
{
  # Do this
}
```

Comment: `undef` **is** the null value. Perl just has a different name for it.